# Adding Pull Request Template to mulitple repository

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am working on pull_request_template.md file, I have to add the same pull request template to multiple repos.

Is there any way to create a single repo for pull request, so that I don't have to pull request templates to multiple repos one by one and the other repos can directly inherit the template?

Comment: If all your repos are in the same GitHub org you can put your default PR templates in a special repo called `.github`, according to [here](https://www.rhysmills.com/post/2021/09/07/set-a-default-pr-template-for-a-github-organisation.html).

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to make 1 `.md` file for PR templates and make it so multiple repositories use them. Just copy and paste the content. You can also download the file and upload it in each repository.